# Php redirect after successful login

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I'm having an issue with a simple verification file, it doesn't redirect to index page after successful login.

Basically the login.php file has the html form for login, the form calls auth.php file which already has the login data and decides if your login and password is correct or not. Now it should redirect to index.php after successful login but it doesn't , instead it just cleans up the form in the login.php file and you keep trying , BUT if you refresh the page ( after successful login ) you get auto redirected to index page.

**Fixed!** changed the code to something even simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($logindata[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"])
```

This bit doesn't look correct; maybe you were looking for:

```
if($logindata[$_POST["password"]]==$_POST["password"])
```

Comment: nope it checks the array if the password is at the same place as the username array.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes headers does not work well for some reasons, instead try to use a simple html redirect like this:

```
<?php
$usernames = array("user1", "user2");
$passwords = array("pass1", "pass2");
$page = "index.php";
for($i=0;$i<count($usernames);$i++){  
    $logindata[$usernames[$i]]=$passwords[$i]; 
}
    $found = 0; 
    for($i=0;$i<count($usernames);$i++) {    
        if ($usernames[$i] == $_POST["username"])    {    
        $found = 1;    
        } 
        } 
        if ($found == 0) {   

            $redirect_url = "./login.php?login_error=1"

        }

if($logindata[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]) {        
    session_start();    
    $_SESSION["username"]=$_POST["username"]; 

$redirect_url = "./index.php"

    } 
    else {    
        $redirect_url = "./login.php?login_error=2"

    }

    echo "<center><br><br><br><p>You will be redirected in about 2 seconds. If not, click this link: <a href='$redirect_url'>Back</a></p></center>";

    ?>
     <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url='<?php echo "$redirect_url"; ?>'/>

        <title>Redirecting...</title>
            </head>
            </html> 

<?php

exit;

?>
```

I presumed the redirect location is in the same folder of the php file. Adjust the var $redirect_url path of they aren't.

Comment: that completely broke the verification

Comment: Header location always work great. If a header location is not working its 99.9% because there is output BEFORE u try to change the headers. For good practise you should always follow a `header('Location: http://www.example.com');` with an `exit;`